# How read specific positions strings and if they match, then print all the line in python?

Tags: python, string, position

I'm learning python. I want to do this:

I have a text file with a lot of lines like this (each line have 26 strings, some strings can be whitespaces or not, followed the number of line):

```
      BBBTHTHTTTTCCCHHHHHH       1
CCCTTTTHHHHHHHHHHHTTTTTTTT       2
TTTTTTTTTTHHHHHHHHCCCCCC         3
CTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTHHHHHHHHH       4
```

I want to read the string from 22 to 26 position, and if all these positions are H,  then print the complete line. For example:

```
      BBBTHTHTTTTCCCHHHHHH       1
CTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTHHHHHHHHH       4
```

My script is this

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line[22:26]=="H"]
print lines
```

anybody can help me to fix it? Thanks for your support and tips.

Comment: This is incorrect: `if line[22:26]=="H" `
Do you want to just print the lines or get a list with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        if i[21:26]=='HHHHH':
            print(i)
```

Comment: use `== ` not `=`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and `endswith()`

```
res = [line for line in f if line.split()[0].endswith('H' * (26 - 21))]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[' BBBTHTHTTTTCCCHHHHHH       1', 'CTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTHHHHHHHHH       4']
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be :

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = '\n'.join([l for l in f.read().splitlines() if l[22:26] == 'HHHH'])
print(lines)
```